# BxSlider is calculating wrong width at first load

Tags: bxslider

I am using bxslider; The data which i am passing is dynamic via json and rendering it through Handlebars. I have used require.js as AMD lib for my project.

wheneven i try to load view/page. Bxslider within it does not loaded the image correctly for first time. As soon as i refresh the page it works fine.

At first time

```
element.style {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-right: 12px;
    position: relative;
    width: 28px;
}
```

After refresh

```
element.style {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-right: 12px;
    position: relative;
    width: 95px;
}
```

Initialize slider as:

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 5,
    slideWidth: 95,
    slideMargin: 12,
    pager: false,
    infiniteLoop: false
});
```

BxSlider is calculating wrong width at first load. Did anyone faced such issues? Any rapid fixes that i needs to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was loading adding/removing some class. after bxslider code block. Added that thing in onSliderLoad event. and it worked fine.